# How do I use python to create outlook events in multiple calendars

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32

This is the code I've been using. It works when I want to create an appointment, but only in my main calendar. Do any of you know how to create the appointments in a secondary calendar?

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")


def sendMeeting():
  appt = outlook.CreateItem(1) # AppointmentItem
  appt.Start = "2021-5-28 16:10" # yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm
  appt.Subject = "Fake meeting"
  appt.Duration = 30 # In minutes (60 Minutes)
  appt.Location = "The bat cave"

  appt.Save()
  appt.Send()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean a secondary Exchange account in the profile? Or a delegate Exchange mailbox?
In the former case, open the store from the `Namespace.Stores` collection, open the Calendar folder using `Store.GetDefaulFolder(olFolderCalendar)`, create new item using `MAPIFolder.Items.Add`. In the latter case, you can use `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(Recipient, olFolderCalendar)` (where Recipient can be retrieved from `Namespace.CreateRecipient`).

If it is a subfolder in your primary store, you can access it from its parent folder and call `MAPIFolder.Items.Add`.  E.g. if it is a subfolder of your default Calendar folder, use `outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Folders.Item("The name")`. If it is on the same level as your Calendar folder, use `outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Parent.Folders.Item("The name")`.

Comment: It's more that I have my default email account and I created a sub-calendar within that email account (my work calendar). I have trouble accessing that one because it's not the default calendar.

Comment: If I could ask one more question, what format does the .add need to be in? I added: MapiFolder =outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(9).Folders.Item("Leave calendar")
MapiFolder.add(appt)                                                                                                  with appt defined as a win32com appointment item, but it returns an error. Does it need to be JSON?

Comment: OOM knows another about JSON. Items.Add takes either one of the OlItemType enums (you need olAppointmentItem, which is 1), or the message class (a string) - in your case, that would be IPM.Appointment.